# Selenium RC "driver.quit()" throwing error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium `selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar` with latest Firefox version 45 and getting below exception. Everything was working fine for more than 1 year. What's wrong with `Firefox 45`

```
tearDown(selenium.tests.AppProfileTests)  Time elapsed: 18.317 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'SKOTWAL', ip: '172.16.21.139', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Session ID: d8d1af96-a1e9-446a-ab2d-e4520b5d4b62
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=d8d1af96-a1e9-446a-ab2d-e4520b5d4b62, version=44.0.2, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:423)
        at selenium.SeleniumTestBase.tearDown(SeleniumTestBase.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'SKOTWAL', ip: '172.16.21.139', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:423)
        at selenium.SeleniumTestBase.tearDown(SeleniumTestBase.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:451)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils$ProcessWaiter.run(ProcessUtils.java:164)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's looks like you are using selenium grid ... is other slave machine also have the same version of selenium server?

Comment: I just have only one master instance & no master slave topology

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of the stack trace you can see this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:451)
```

The [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) tells you why:

> InterruptedException - if the current thread is interrupted by another thread while it is waiting, then the wait is ended and an InterruptedException is [thrown](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#l253).

The first thing I can think of is TestNG (or some other mechanism of yours) having a timed wait on the `tearDown` to finish.

Edit:
I just saw, that you're using it with Firefox **45**, which is Beta. Stable is on 44.0.2, yet. Selenium's browser support states it only support already released versions. At least for my English.

So it is possible, that you've encountered a change that is not yet implemented in Selenium.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue with Firefox 36. Is this selenium product issue?

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda - Have you tried with latest Firefox?